# Echo from inner function not printed (powershell)

Tags: powershell, output

I have two functions: GetEvents and GeneralPrint. The output I see changes if I call GetEvents directly or by GeneralPrint.

GeneralPrint has code:

```
....
    echo "XXXX"
    echo "-------"
    GetEvents 
}
```

GetEvents has code:

```
echo "events"
$t=@(Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable $filter -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | select -ExpandProperty TimeCreated )
foreach($i in $t) {echo $i}
```

If I run `GeneralPrint`
I get

```
XXXX
----
events
```

Then I get `N` blank lines.

If I run `GetEvents` directly from powershell console I get all output and `N` event dates as expected.

---

I tried `echo $(GetEvents)` and other variants.

(powershell 5)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: We don't know what $filter is.  It works for me.  Maybe try it without -erroraction.  If you mix different objects with (implied) format-table, you may not see all the properties.